# How to find all documents with all specified array values in it in mongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, database

This is my collection

```
{
    "_id" : ..., 
    "name" : "sport", 
}
{
    "_id" : ..., 
    "name" : "art", 
}
{
    "_id" : ..., 
    "name" : "cars", 
}
```

This is an array I have got `["cars","sport"]`
I just want to make sure that I have got `cars` **and** `sport` in my collection, if not(or just one doesn't exist) I would like to receive **nothing**.
I'm looking for a array-friendly like query like **$in** but **and** mode.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking ..??

`db.colllection.find( {$and: [ {"name": {$in: ["cars"]}}, 
                       {"name": {$in: ["sports"]}}
                     ]
})`

Comment: No, this is the answer, thanks. this just works if it finds any, or both.

Answer (score 0):

following query should help you achieve this

```
//change test with your collection name
db.getCollection('test').aggregate(
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "collectionOfNames",
            "names": {$addToSet: "$name"}
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {"names": {$all: ["cars", "sport"]}}

    }
)
```

We use $group to create an array "names" of the property **name** across all documents.
Then using $match and [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) we check to make sure that the array "names" contains all of the elements from our query array.

Is this what you are looking for?